# Scroll to view in ajax page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, scroll, overflow

The situation is this: 
I have a div with overflow auto containing a table. The page containing this div is ajaxed into a main page. I want a javascript (jquery is fine) method to run on the ajaxed page load that scrolls the div to a certain tr with an id. What's the best method to do this? I've added a small scale example below.

**ATTEMPTED**

*adjusting ajax call to include scrolltoview (url#id) [Result: 404 error object not found]*

*jquery scrollTop [Result:currently testing. no scrolling occuring]*

AJAX Page

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" Inherits="APTEIT.scrolltest" %>
<script src="Utilities/Javascript/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#divy").scrollTop($("#25").position().top);
    });
</script>
```

AJAX CS (just to populate the table easily)

```
using System;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.HtmlControls;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

namespace APTEIT
{
    /*Codebehind for import.aspx*/
    public class scrolltest: Page
    {
        public scrolltest()
        {
        }

        protected void Page_Load()
        {
            Response.Write("<div style=\"overflow:auto;border-style:solid;border-width:2px;border-color:Black;height:200px;width:200px;\" id=\"divy\">");
            Response.Write("<table style=\"border-collapse:collapse\"><tr><th>Number</th><th>Thingy</th></tr>");
            for(int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
            {
                Response.Write("<tr id=\"" + i + "\"><td style=\"border-style:solid;border-width:1px;border-color:black;\">" + i + "</td><td style=\"border-style:solid;border-width:1px;border-color:black;\">thingy" + i + "</td></tr>");
            }
            Response.Write("</table></div>");
        }

    }
}
```

Main Page(ajax method not included. simply fills "divy2" with asynchronous load of ajax page)

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" %>
<html>
<head>
<script src="Utilities/Javascript/Utilities.js"></script>
<script src="Utilities/Javascript/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        ajax("scrolltest.aspx", "divy2");
    });
</script>
<div id="divy2">

</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: @Nikhil Haven't written any javascript for this function yet. I'm working on getting a smaller example of the HTML to post, but right now it's a larger part of a whole. I'm looking for some direction on how to start first off.

Comment: @Nikhil I've added some code above now to provide an example of what I'm trying to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`.position()`](http://api.jquery.com/position/) to find out the `TR`'s position relative to the parent `DIV`, and then use [`.scrollTop()`](http://api.jquery.com/scrollTop/) to set the `DIV` scroll bar to the top of the `TR` element.

So, you can use something like this:
`$("div").scrollTop($("div tr#id").position().top);​`

I've set up an example of it here: http://jsfiddle.net/dvirazulay/7mQmD/

Comment: This did not work for me. I've added my attempted code to the OP for reference. Could it be because the page is ajaxed in?

Comment: You should execute this line after loading the data into `divy2`, and not just at document ready. Best way would be to integrate it with your `ajax()` call at the success handler, because otherwise you are not promised the data will be ready before trying to change the scroll position.

Comment: Implemented a handler on ajax load. Worked like a charm. Thanks!